# How to setup a NNTP server for Usenet?

Tags: linux

i have to setup an internal usenet server but i can't find any tutorial or advice. I have to use Linux.

Can you suggest me any tutorial or free (like beer :-) ) software ?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you live that you get beer for free? We have to pay for it. Something to do with the brewery workers wanting to feed their families, or some such nonsense.

Comment: lol, true it's a sad world where you have to pay for beer :-)

Comment: @John, maybe if you were more friendly you wouldn't always have to buy your own beer. :-)

Comment: @Paul, we have names for people who rely on others to buy their beer for them.

Answer (score 7):

- Install inn (apt-get install inn2)
- Edit /etc/news/inn.conf

Since you said "internal", I assume you aren't looking for feeds or getting any feeds, so you don't need to configure `incoming.conf`, `innfeed.conf`, or `newsfeeds`.

- Create any local newsgroups with `ctlinnd newgroup my.groupname y ''`

At that point, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've said internal because only internal client can access this server but it has to fetch standard usenet group. How can i connect my inn installation to receive standard usenet group?

Comment: If you want standard usenet groups, then you need to arrange for somebody to feed you, and you have to feed them back.  If you want a simple text-only feed, you can often arrange those for free.  If you want all the binaries (and be prepared for a firehose of data), you'll probably have to pay.

Comment: Again tanks for your fast reply. We only need tex-only feed. Can you suggest any free provider to begin with? What i don't know is how my server knows about new posts. It fetches with a fixed interval a server or some server send new messages to my server (push or pull ?) ?

Comment: Usenet feeding can be via push or pull.  Push is more efficient.  As for finding usenet peers, that can be tricky.

Comment: Don't forget that you'll need a MASSIVE amount of hard drive space, even for the tex only feed.

Comment: That's not true.  I carry a full big-8 and most of alt (except alt.sex and alt.binaries) and a bunch of regional heirarchies, and my spool is about 2.5Gb.  Remember that before alt.binaries came along, we could push an entire feed via uucp over a 2400 bps modem.

Comment: Consider leafnode to provide a local server with a slow uplink.